# in R, how can I see if three elements of a character vector are the same out of a vector of length 5

Tags: r, vector, element, poker

I have a poker hand and I need to check for three of a kind.  Is there a way to see if 3 elements in the vector are the same but the other 2 are different?

E.g.:

```
hand <- c("Q","Q","6","5","Q")
```

Should return `TRUE` for three of a kind.

```
hand2 <- c("Q","Q","6","6","Q")
```

...would be a full-house though, and shouldn't be identified as a three of a kind.

Comment: @RichardScriven - `rle` will require sorting - something like `any(table(hand)==3) & sum(table(hand)==1)==2` will probably do it.

Comment: Depends on how the cards are indicated. Post an example of a hand that should match and one that shouldn't.

Comment: @PierreLafortune - i've just added an example hand - maybe OP can clarify this is what they want.

Comment: haha That's nice of you but won't do any good if the hands are written in poker talk. Like this R walk-through https://stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring12/sta104.1/Homework/SimHW1.pdf. If rank and suit are indicated, you must separate them first then use the methods above.

Comment: @PierreLafortune - sure, there's extra considerations in taking into account suits of cards, but the general question of `see if 3 elements in the vector are the same but the other 2 are different` seems perfectly answerable with a simplified example.

Comment: I think it's a major consideration that the OP failed to mention. I'm downvoting their question but upvoting your effort :)

Comment: I already have the hand broken down to just the "values" of 2-10,JQKA so the suits are being ignored now.  The actual hand has suits but I used sort(table(hand[,1])) or some sort to separate it, if this makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

Using `table` and some logic checking should get you there:

```
tab <- table(hand)
#hand
#5 6 Q 
#1 1 3
any(tab==3) & (sum(tab==1)==2)
#[1] TRUE

tab <- table(hand2)
#hand2
#6 Q 
#2 3 
any(tab==3) & (sum(tab==1)==2)
#[1] FALSE
```

This works because `any` will look across the `tab`le, checking if there are any card values repeated 3 times. The `tab==1` part of the function checks if any values in the `tab`le are equal to 1, returning `TRUE` or `FALSE` for each part of the table. `sum`-ing `TRUE/FALSE` values is equivalent to summing `1/0` values, so if you check that you had a sum of `2` for the other cards, you can be sure they are different.

Comment: I give this answer my full seal of approval

Comment: @RichardScriven - can I have a laminated certificate of that to hang on my office wall?

Comment: Thanks so much! I have been trying to figure this out for hours lol. As you can tell, I just started using R this semester and am not a programmer of any sort.

Comment: also `any(tab==3) & (length(tab)==3)`

Comment: In the same spirit as jbaums ans; make the 2nd test '!any(tab==2)'